# How do I add and call a helper script in a Juju charm?

Tags: juju, charms

I have a charm where I'd like to be able to call a small Python script in one of the hooks as part of its execution.  Where do I put that helper script?  Can I put it in the hooks directory and get it included?  Then, once it is transfered to the remote machine, where is it located so that I can execute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire directory of the charm (the root being the dir with metadata.yaml) is bundled and unpacked on the service unit including permission bits (ownership is always transferred to root:root). Hooks are always run with the charm root as current working directory, and saved in $CHARM_DIR.

So, you can put the scripts wherever you want. There's no agreement yet on the best practice for this. Some people feel that *only* hooks should be in the hooks dir, and external scripts should be in a different dir off the root. Others just put everything in hooks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm trying it now but it seems my Openstack setup just broke.  Hopefully I'll be able to verify here real soon!

Comment: Great!  Works here.  I made a separate helpers directory and executed my script with $CHARM_DIR/helpers/myhelper.  Thanks!